# PyAudio Error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _win32sysloader: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, pyaudio

I've been trying to install `PyAudio` to my Anaconda virtual environment to mess around with some voice command stuff, but unfortunately I ran into a couple of errors. The first was a `pywin32` error missing some `DLLs` which I fixed by copy and pasting the files from elsewhere. Then I got an error saying

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _win32sysloader: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

and I can't figure out what's wrong.
My Python version is 3.9.5 - 64bit
and my PyAudio seems to be 64bit too, so this error makes no sense to me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `win32` in the message has nothing to do with whether your system is 32 bit or 64 bit. `win32` is the name for a Microsoft API, not a hardware architecture. That said, it is likely that your error message is caused by your 64-bit Python trying to import a 32-bit DLL. Try this: uninstall `PyAudio`, and download the 64-bit binary from Christoph Gohlke's site (taking care to get the right wheel for amd64 and your version of Python) and install that.

Comment: Already tried using a 64-bit wheel from Christoph Gohlke's site

Comment: Does it work outside Anaconda?

Comment: I can't install `PyAudio` because my python version is too high, so an environment is suitable for me. Thought it seems the compatible modules run just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening an Anaconda prompt as an Admin and then activate your environment. Then run `sfc /scannow` and wait. This fixed the problem for me since my files were corrupted.